# Primitive values passed to child component are undefined in constructor in Angular 2

Tags: input, angular, components

I am pretty new to angular 2.
I need to create a reusable component of user profile picture, that got 2 inputs of height and width, and finally represents a picture in the correct size.

My component call in parent.html :

```
<user-profile-pic [height]="50" [width]="50" [counterValue]="myValue"></user-profile-pic>
```

my component user-profile-pic :

```
import {Component,Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector : 'user-profile-pic',  
  template: '<img src="http://to/picture.png"> ',
  inputs:['width','height']
})

export class UserProfilePic {
    /*
    @Input() height : String;
    @Input() width : String;
*/
public height:String;
public width:String;
  constructor() {
      console.log("This is the height ",this.height," And the width : ",this.width);
  }

}
```

The console logs my undefined both on height and width..
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Inputs are not yet set in the constructor. They are set the first time `ngOnChanges()` is called (called for every update). `ngOnInit()` is called after `ngOnChanges()` is called the first time.

Just change your code to

```
export class UserProfilePic {
    /*
    @Input() height : String;
    @Input() width : String;
*/
public height:String;
public width:String;
ngOnInit() {
      console.log("This is the height ",this.height," And the width : ",this.width);
  }
}
```

From your example it looks like your component is also missing a `counterValue` input.

Comment: Thank you very much . [and about the counterValue - its ok, I know it ]

Answer (score 2):

Try that:

```
import {Component,Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector : 'user-profile-pic',  
  template: '<img src="http://to/picture.png"> '
})

export class UserProfilePic implements OnInit {
    @Input() height : String;
    @Input() width : String;

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log("This is the height ",this.height," And the width : ",this.width);
  }

}
```